# What deep learning methods should I explore for my panel data where one country is fixed?

Tags: neural-networks, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

The data looks like the following image and is available from 1980 to 2019:
[image]

As you can see, nation 1 doesn't differ in any of the panels; only country 2 does and the country 2s for each panel remain same. What deep learning technique should I to explore to create a research report on it? I've seen a [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/329328/356702) on this site that recommended using LSTMs for panel data, but I'm not sure if that's the best strategy for my dataset. I did more research on LSTMs, and it appears to be suitable for my goal of prediction based on all values given its reliance on long term memory. Can someone guide me please?

Edits based on comments:

- I will have >70000 observations. In the worst case where I restrict the time series range, I will land up with 20k observations.  I understand that this might be less, so I am open to the possibility of allowing variation in country 1 and then using the model for prediction of my current country.
- I have around 6-10 variables (features) that determine the "Value" column in the table.

Comment: Why do you want to use deep learning at all..? They are not great for tabular data. I also guess you don’t have tons of this data, so also it’s unlikely to work well. There are many reasons why other models would be preferable.

Comment: @Tim I have this data from for 20 years and many dependent variables (around 10) for each pair of observations and >50 Country B's so that will mean >20*50 = 1000 observations

Comment: So you have little data and you should stick to a simple model like linear regression. Definitely not deep learning.

Comment: @Tim since deep learning hasn't been used much in the context that I am exploring, doesn't it make for a good research problem?

Comment: @Tim I am open to the possibility of allowing variation in country 1. That will give me a very big dataset.

Comment: If you want to show how bad it can get, sure, but you would need simulated data with known ground truth to show that. But we already know that deep learning needs a lot of data, otherwise overfits, and there are better alternatives for tabular data.

Comment: @Tim What are your thoughts on allowing variation in country 1 to get around 50k datapoints and then using my model for prediction of the currently chosen country 1?

Comment: You didn’t give us much details so it’s hard to comment but usually other models outperform deep learning models, so before using deep learning you should make sure that everything else failed. And linear (or logistic) regression should be the first thing to try.

Comment: @Tim I will be using the CEPII Gravity Dataset which has over 700k observations. For my country A alone it has 70k datapoints and in the worst case if I restrict the range, it will have 20k datapoints. I am sorry for not checking the accurate number of observations earlier. Could you please let me know your thoughts now? Sorry for the trouble again!

Comment: Please see this paper: https://www.usitc.gov/publications/332/working_papers/neural_networks_and_international_trade_-_compiled_draft_06.pdf

It appears that Neural Network did a good job in forecasting trade as compared to OLS

Answer (score 0):

*Extending comments into an answer:*

You should start by *not using* deep learning. You have tabular data and for such data traditional statistical and machine learning models are successfully used both in the industry and in Kaggle competitions [as noticed by Szilard Pafka](https://twitter.com/SzilardPafka/status/1062786102946197507). There are many empirical studies showing that traditional machine learning models outperform deep learning like [this by Javier Rodriguez](https://jrzaurin.github.io/infinitoml/2021/05/28/pytorch-widedeep_iv.html) or the one by [Ravid Shwartz-Ziv and Amitai Armon (2021)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.03253) and many more.

You seem to be talking about time-series data and for such data traditional models also outperform neural networks. A great example is the [M-competition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makridakis_Competitions) that started in 1982 and already had five rounds (the last ended recently) where competitors use different models for thousands of time-series. In each competition, we saw simpler, traditional models outperform neural networks, where the only exception was the last competition where a hybrid model combining a traditional approach with a neural network won.

In the comment, you quoted [this paper](https://www.usitc.gov/publications/332/working_papers/neural_networks_and_international_trade_-_compiled_draft_06.pdf) by Wohl and Kennedy (2018), as an example of a neural network giving better results than another model, but I am afraid it suffers from exactly the kind of biases we can see in much similar research: the authors use overtly simplistic model and compare it to the neural network. What this research shows is that a neural network beats a trivial benchmark, but it tells us nothing about its performance vs a more reasonable model.

This of course does not say that neural networks never work for such problems. It says that with other models you have a higher chance of getting better results. You should try neural networks for tabular data only after you proved that nothing else worked. Otherwise, you are throwing an overtly complicated model at the problem, that is likely to overfit.

Comment: Could you give me an example of a ML technique I could employ? For some reason, when I query on google for ML methods on tabular data, the top results are for Deep Learning.

Comment: @learner it depends on the details of your problem, but all the traditional machine learning work with tabular data.